# Return result less than 2seconds

Tags: c

I have an exercise that tells me to calculate the square root, but my program returns the result in 6 seconds, how I can return the square root in less than 2 seconds?

This is my implementation

```
  1 /* ************************************************************************** */
  2 /*                                                                            */
  3 /*                                                        :::      ::::::::   */
  4 /*   ft_sqrt.c                                          :+:      :+:    :+:   */
  5 /*                                                    +:+ +:+         +:+     */
  6 /*   By: wjean-ma <wjean-ma@student.42.fr>          +#+  +:+       +#+        */
  7 /*                                                +#+#+#+#+#+   +#+           */
  8 /*   Created: 2015/07/13 13:28:12 by wjean-ma          #+#    #+#             */
  9 /*   Updated: 2015/07/14 16:48:21 by wjean-ma         ###   ########.fr       */
 10 /*                                                                            */
 11 /* ************************************************************************** */
 12
 13 int     ft_sqrt(int nb)
 14 {
 15     int i;
 16     int a;
 17
 18     a = 0;
 19     i = 0;
 20     if (nb <= 0)
 21         return (0);
 22     while (i < nb)
 23     {
 24         a = nb - (i * i);
 25         if (a == 0)
 26             return (i);
 27         else if (a < 0)
 28             return (0);
 29         ++i;
 30     }
 31     return (i);
 32 }
```

Comment: Make a better algorithm.

Comment: Include math.h and use log().

Comment: Include math.h and use pow()

Comment: @this `log` for square root? Interesting.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ah mental misstep,  you know what I meant.

Comment: @EugeneSh.`pow( 10.0, log10( x ) / 2.0 )`   Simples!

Comment: Get a CPU that is approximately 3x faster?

Answer (score 1):

Newton's method is an easy method to implement and is usually fast enough.  See https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/chapter1/node9.html

The idea is that you keep averaging your current_guess and argument / curent_guess until your guess is close enough.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


double square_root(double num) {
    double result = 1;
    double range = num * 0.001; /* Answer within 1/10 of a percent. */
    while(abs(result*result - num) > range) {
        result = (result + num/result) / 2;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <number>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%g\n", square_root(atof(argv[1])));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A trundle like this is very inefficient.

Solve it using Newton-Raphson instead. That will converge extremely quickly (and is how the ancient Babylonians tackled this problem).

Even a bisection, with your starting points being 0 and half the number, would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go like binary search algorithm.  Breaking the range of solution into parts and then finding the solution. for eg  if the number is 625 try sqaure of (625/2) i.e.it results a huge value so continue the process where you can get an approximation and can find quickly.

Hope this helps